# Node.js saying that a function is not a function

Tags: node.js, minecraft

My goal is to create a minecraft bot user with mineflayer. I installed node.js and installed mineflayer from terminal, then made a variable that was `require('mineflayer')`. I then used

```js
const mineflayer=require('mineflayer');
const bot=mineflayer.createBot({
    host:'minehut.gg', //only for test purposes
    username: 'MyUserName',
    password: 'myPWD'
});

const plankRecipe = bot.recipesFor(5)[0];
```

However, on the last line of that snippet, it throws the following:
`TypeError: bot.recipesFor is not a function` . Why is it doing this, and how do I get it to recognize that it is a function? My only theory so far is that it failed to connect and just isn't telling me that it couldn't properly make the bot object.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
the WebStorm debugger says bot is an EventEmitter object, not a Bot object as expected. Does this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mineflayer, bots, when created do not have any methods on them (besides the EventEmitter ones). The bot is given its methods when you log in.

This makes sense, as bots cannot really do much if they aren't connected to a game. Even crafting recipes are server-side.

This would be the correct code:

```js
const mineflayer = require("mineflayer"),
  bot = mineflayer.createBot({
    host: "example.com",
    username: "my_username",
    password: "my_password"
  });

bot.once("login", () => {
  const plankRecipe = bot.recipesFor(5)[0];
});
```

See one of their [examples](https://github.com/PrismarineJS/mineflayer/blob/master/examples/anvil.js).

Unfortunately, mineflayer's API documentation doesn't make it easy to realize this.

The error `TypeError: bot.recipesFor is not a function` means exactly what it says: the 'function' you are trying to call is not a function, which could mean that it doesn't exist or is a variable that is not a function.

Answer (score -1):

I've checked the official documentation and recipesFor method accepts 4 arguements

you can check the documentation [here](https://github.com/PrismarineJS/mineflayer/blob/master/docs/api.md#botrecipesforitemtype-metadata-minresultcount-craftingtable)

Comment: adding all the parameters didn't change the response. It doesn't error if I put the entire thing inside a function, then call that function from bot.once('spawn',thefunction). However, I found out that that doesn't actually run the code, so I would assume a connection error is at play here or something